# 2 level dropdown menus in bootstrap working only with click

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to force nested dropdown menu without **hover**. Currently, code below, shows only 
nested dropdown menu only on activated with **hover**. I want to force it only with click, so that in mobile version of website it would cause any problems. Effect that i'm trying to achieve looks like this: http://www.meanthemes.com/demo/meanmenu/demo.html

Approaches:

1. I tried to put `dropdown-toggle` inside `drop-down-toggle`, but the nested dropdown will not be displayed.

   ```
   <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav">
   <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Buildings/Land <b class="caret"></b></a>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu">

     <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a tabindex="-2" href="#"><img src="icons/huron-river-prot_icon.png" class="icons-images">Huron River Protection</a>
       <ul class="dropdown-menu">
         <li><a href="#"><img src="icons/green-roof_icon.png" class="icons-images">Green Roof</a></li>
         <li><a href="#"><img src="icons/huron-river-prot_icon.png" class="icons-images">Porous pavement</a></li>
         <li><a href="#"><img src="icons/retention-detention_icon.png" class="icons-images">Retention/detention</a></li>
       </ul>
     </li>

      </ul>
         </li>         
   </ul>
    </div>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar.
I create a fiddle for you :)

the HTML is very much like yours. I used jquery to identify the second level menus and open them when clicked.

```
     $(document).ready(function(){
     $('.dropdown .dropdown').each(function(){
         var $self = $(this);
         var handle = $self.children('[data-toggle="dropdown"]');
         $(handle).click(function(){
             var submenu = $self.children('.dropdown-menu');
             $(submenu).toggle();
             return false;
         });
     });
 });
```

and I had to use the following CSS on top of bootstrap so that the second level menu would open to the side.

```
.dropdown-menu .dropdown-menu {
top: 0;
left: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/elewinso/Upmx8/

I hope this helps.